# Unreal CDXGIBaseAdapter::InternalGetAdapterDesc EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION reading address 0x00000000000000d0

Tags: windows, unreal-engine4, game-development, dxgi

I'm a game developer using Unreal Engine 4. I'm having the issue where the packaged game would often crash on startup with `CDXGIBaseAdapter::InternalGetAdapterDesc EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION reading address 0x00000000000000d0`. Could anyone shed some light here?

[Callstack screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kkFBH.png)

Comment: Try w/o Steam installed: https://steamcommunity.com/discussions/forum/1/1520386297697004596/

Comment: Update #1: Part of the crash was due to outdated Epic Launcher without EOS installed. I don’t know how Epic Launcher issue is related to dxgi but it fixed some of the crashes.